# Electron app hangs on quitting even though all quit events successfully fired

Tags: electron, freeze, electron-builder

I've been trying to debug an issue with our electron app for a while now but it's becoming quite the conundrum.

Issue: Intermittently, when using the quit shortcut (**cmd+Q**), the app UI successfully goes away but it stays in the menu bar(mac)/notification try(win) and displays the beachball of death on hover.

And i have to go to activity monitor to actually force close it
[app not responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNzfZ.png)

This only happens with the packaged production app and not in dev mode. On looking through the logs it seems all the quit events are properly hit.

```
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  log.info('All windows closed');

  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
// Logs to help nail down quit failures
app.on('will-quit', () => log.info('App will quit'));
app.on('quit', () => log.info('App is quitting'));

app.on('before-quit', async () => {
 log.info('Attempting to quit app');
}
```

tail of log.log

```
[2019-02-04 14:29:34.543] [info] electron: message received: windows-info
[2019-02-04 14:29:35.831] [info] Attempting to quit app
[2019-02-04 14:29:35.919] [info] stopping mouse tracking
[2019-02-04 14:29:36.073] [info] App will quit
[2019-02-04 14:29:36.079] [info] App is quitting
[2019-02-04 14:29:36.127] [info]  mac binary: main.swift:49 : sendPayload(messageToSend:): {"type":"will-close-expectedly"}

[2019-02-04 14:29:36.128] [info] electron: message received: will-close-expectedly
[2019-02-04 14:29:36.130] [info] daemon binary /Applications/Loom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/dist/binaries/loom-mac-recorderproduction exited
[2019-02-04 14:29:37.555] [error] No menubar present
[2019-02-04 14:29:37.676] [error] No menubar present
[2019-02-04 14:29:39.537] [error] No menubar present
[2019-02-04 14:29:39.675] [error] No menubar present
[2019-02-04 14:29:41.653] [error] No menubar present
[2019-02-04 14:29:41.790] [error] No menubar present
```

As you can see from the log all the quit events fire in correct order but the app still stays in the mac menubar. An interesting thing that happens is the `[error] No menubar present`. This shows up whenever i try to click on the icon in the menubar. It *should* throw when it's trying to *hide* the app menu.
This is the menubar in question: https://github.com/maxogden/menubar.

This is what a successful quit log looks like

```
019-02-04 14:52:36.722] [info] Attempting to quit app
[2019-02-04 14:52:36.740] [info] stopping mouse tracking
[2019-02-04 14:52:36.868] [info] App will quit
[2019-02-04 14:52:36.874] [info] App is quitting
[2019-02-04 14:52:36.887] [info]  mac binary: main.swift:49 : sendPayload(messageToSend:): {"type":"will-close-expectedly"}

[2019-02-04 14:52:36.889] [info] daemon binary /Applications/LoomStaging.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/dist/binaries/loom-mac-recorderstaging exited
```

Is there any way to dig into what is making the app hang since there don't seem to be any errors thrown in the main process, just this ghost state where all UI elements have vanished but the process sticks around. Is there a way to dig deeper into what's happening/where it is hanging up.

Another point of interest is that whenever we do a quitAndInstall on update (using electron-builder), if the aforementioned menubar is `hidden`, then almost always we hit this weird hung up state, but when the menubar is visible and we initiate a quitAndInstall, it works fine.

Comment: Hope you find a solution to this interesting problem. It may not be relevant to your situation but at times I've found that when my main process hangs when quitting, it is because I have a still-connected debugger listening to one of the processes. Once I find and kill the debugger, my main process can quit. Another suggestion is to examine what listeners are listening on events on the electron app object, it might give insight to the root of your issue

Answer (score 0):

I've created test [repo](https://github.com/sanperrier/menubar-test) with barebone example.

On my machine it works fine (i removed checks for `process.platform` in `window-all-closed` event, but i tested with and without these checks - works both ways):

```
const { menubar } = require('menubar');
const { app, Menu, Tray, autoUpdater, dialog } = require('electron');

autoUpdater.setFeedURL(`https://update.electronjs.org/sanperrier/menubar-test/${process.platform}-${process.arch}/${app.getVersion()}`);

autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', () => {
    dialog.showMessageBox({
        title: "No available updates",
        message: `No available updates\ncurrent version: ${app.getVersion()}`
    });
});

autoUpdater.on('update-available', () => {
    dialog.showMessageBox({
        title: "Update is downloading",
        message: `Update is downloading\ncurrent version: ${app.getVersion()}`
    });
});

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', async (e, notes, name) => {
    await dialog.showMessageBox({
        title: "Update downloaded",
        message: `Update downloaded\ncurrent version: ${app.getVersion()}\nnew version: ${name}`,
        detail: notes
    });

    autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
});

app.on('ready', () => {
    const tray = new Tray(require.resolve('menubar/assets/IconTemplate.png'));
    const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: `Check for updates and install (current: ${app.getVersion()})`,
            type: 'normal',
            click: () => autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
        },
        {
            label: 'Close window',
            type: 'normal',
            click: () => mb.window?.close()
        },
        {
            label: 'Exit',
            type: 'normal',
            click: () => app.quit()
        }
    ]);
    tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

    const mb = menubar({ tray });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', e => {
    console.log('window-all-closed');

    // if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    // }
});

app.on('before-quit', () => console.log('before-quit'));
app.on('will-quit', () => console.log('will-quit'));
app.on('quit', async () => console.log('quit'));
```

works fine.

Possible issues:

1. old version of electron
2. maybe calling `app.quit()` in `window-all-closed` for `darwin` platform will help
3. i searched for "No menubar present" in `menubar` sources and found nothing, so this error originates from your code or 3rd party code. Or maybe old version of `menubar`?

Please, clarify, what do you mean by "menubar is `hidden`".

As a workaround, you can try to add `app.exit(0)` to `quit` event handler. I'm not sure will it break `autoUpdate.quitAndInstall()`. I tested it with code like this: `app.on('quit', () => { console.log('quit'); app.exit(0); })` and it worked fine:

```
$ menubar-test.app/Contents/MacOS/menubar-test 
2020-08-08 13:35:20.689 menubar-test[62834:6522941] Download completed to: file:///Users/sanperrier/Library/Caches/com.electron.menubar-test.ShipIt/update.aaHFVTv/menubar-test-darwin-x64-1.1.11.zip
before-quit
will-quit
quit
```

App downloaded update and restarted (with update installed).

Hope this helps. Feel free to fork my repo and use it to nail down the root cause of the problem.